# Is a virtualized guest host limited by the host system max concurrent connections

Tags: hyper-v, connection, windows-10, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to test a server environment on my windows 10 professional.

I'm running windows server 2016 as a guest host with hyper-v

I need to test our application (angular) with 30/40 clients connecting on IIS.

I was wondering if, among other limitations, the windows10 concurrent connection limit where applied to the hyper-v guest host though
 it is a server OS that does not have them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Generally the host limit is something that only applies to CERTAIN services, so IIRC even without server it would not apply to IIS anyway. Not sure, but.... well...

But anyhow, on Hyper-V the host never sees connections, just ethernet packets - because that is what is the "common ground" that the VM uses to connect to the outside world..

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/286727b9-5a26-40d0-a3d8-fa2cb73dce92/hyperv-connection-limit?forum=winserverhyperv

has some infos about that.